# Conditional validation based on array element - Avoid warning 'missing type "object" for keyword "properties"'

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I have a JSON array containing objects with key value pairs.

```
[
    { "name": "foo" },
    { "name": "bar" }
]
```

If one the `name`'s equals `null` I want to set `maxItems` to `1`.

My schema looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "enum": [null, "foo", "bar"]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "name"
        ]
    },
    "if": {
        "contains": { "properties": { "name": { "const": null } } }
    },
    "then": {
        "maxItems": 1
    }
}
```

It basically works but outputs a warning at compile time:

```
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "#/if/contains" (strictTypes)
```

I am understanding that `properties` is only a keyword for objects and I am applying it to an instance of array here (actually meaning: properties of one of the array's objects), but I have no idea how to solve this properly.

A complete AJV minimal example looks like this:

```
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv();

const schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "enum": [null, "foo", "bar"]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "name"
        ]
    },
    "if": {
        "contains": { "properties": { "name": { "const": null } } }
    },
    "then": {
        "maxItems": 1
    }
};

const data = [
    { name: 'foo' },
    { name: 'bar' }
];

const data2 = [
    { name: null }
];

const data3 = [
    { name: 'foo' },
    { name: null }
];

const validate = ajv.compile(schema); // strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "#/if/contains" (strictTypes)
console.log(validate(data)); // true
console.log(validate(data2)); // true
console.log(validate(data3)); // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the keyword `contains` says that its value must be a valid JSON schema. So this warning makes sense. Why not simply adding a `"type": "object"` to the schema at `contains`?

In your eyes, as a human, this might be not necessary because you already 'know' that the values are objects, but the validator does expect a full schema here to apply to each array value.

Comment: Okay, I completely misunderstood the warning. Using `"contains": { "type": "object", "properties": { "name": { "const": null } } }` resolved the issue. 
Accepting your answer as you have been a litte faster than @Ether.

Answer (score 3):

The specification does not mandate that `"type": "object"` must appear with object-specific keywords such as `properties`. (Indeed, it's often useful to mix and match keywords that correspond to different types, to allow for flexible data input.) Nevertheless, the ajv implementation insists upon doing this.

Your options at this point are adding the extra keywords, pleading with the implementation author to fix this behaviour, or switch to a different implementation.